How to show that the inf / sup of the set of the $n$-th powers of the elements of a set consisting of non-negative real numbers ...?
Let $A$ be a nonempty, bounded (from above) set consisting of non-negative real numbers only, let $n$ be a given positive integer, and let sets $B$ and $C$ be defined as follows:
$$
B := \left\{ a^n \colon a \in A \right\} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad C := \left\{ \sqrt[n]{a} \colon a \in A \right\}. 
$$
Then obviously $B$ and $C$ are also nonempty and bounded. How to rigorously show that
$$
\sup B = \big( \sup A \big)^n \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \inf B = \big( \inf A \big)^n?
$$
And, how to show rigorously that
$$
\sup C = \sqrt[n]{ \sup A } \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \inf C = \sqrt[n]{ \inf A }?
$$
My Attempt:
We show the result about the supremum first. Obviously, $\big( \sup A \big)^n$ is an upper bound for our set $B$ so that $B$ is bounded from above.
How to proceed from here?
Can we prove the required results using only the material in Chapter 1 of Baby Rudin, for example?

Let $A\subseteq[0,M],$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}.$ Let $B=\{a^{n}:a\in A\}.$
Let $u=\sup A.$ By the least upper bound definition of supremum,
$u$ is an upper bound for $A$ and no number $u'<u$ is an upper bound
for for $A.$ I will show $u^{n}$ is the supremum of $B.$ Clearly,
$u^{n}$ is an upper bound for $B.$ If $w<u^{n}$ is an upper bound
for $B,$ then $a^{n}\leq w$ for all $a\in A.$ Hence $a\leq w^{1/n}$
for all $a\in A,$ so $w^{1/n}$ is an upper bound for $A,$ but $w^{1/n}<u.$
Contradicting $u$ is the least upper bound for $A.$
Let $\ell=\inf A.$ By the greatest lower bound definition of infimum,
$\ell$ is a lower bound for $A$ and no number $\ell'>\ell$ is a lower
bound for $A.$ Clearly, $0\leq\ell$ and $\ell^{n}$ is a lower bound
for $B.$ If $m>\ell^{n}$ is a lower bound for $B,$ then $m\leq a^{n}$
for all $a\in A.$ Hence $m^{1/n}\leq a$ for all $a\in A,$ so $m^{1/n}$ is a lower bound for $A$, but $m^{1/n}>\ell.$
Contradicting $\ell$ is the greatest lower bound.
The proofs for the $n$th root are similar.
